# When calling one of my functions in Node.js the program first calls emitHookFactory and gets stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express

I'm running into an issue where my Node.js program gets stuck looping a function (`emitHookFactory` in `\<node_internals>\internal\async_hooks.js`) that I didn't even explicitly call. It happens when I access members or call functions on one of my own classes from my backend application. When I access those members or functions from my frontend app there is no problem.

Examples:

Backend: `comp.UpdateMaster();` immediately goes into `emitHookFactory` and loops indefinitely.
Frontent: `comp.UpdateMaster();` immediately goes into `UpdateMaster` as expected.

The backend code runs inside a `Promise` inside an `Express.js` `Router`'s `get` handler, if that's any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems you're not the only one to have this issue. I found this [post](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/49402) in response to a similar questions that you have. If you are using vscode to try and debug your nodejs application you should set this property:

```
"skipFiles": [
  "<node_internals>/**"
],
```

To your config file in vscode.

Sorry if this isn't your issue, but it seems like this is happening to others.

Comment: I added that to my `launch.json` and the program now works as expected (the underlying problem was that the functions/members I was trying to access didn't exist on the object).